# Python: x ticks time step

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this code that shows me graph at the picture. It shows only some of the month that I have in my df.

```
plot = df_homework.plot(figsize=(14,7), fontsize=14, grid=False)
plot.set_title('Students', fontsize=16)
plot.legend(fontsize=12)
plot.set_ylabel('Students', fontsize=14)
plot.set_xlabel('Date start', fontsize=14)
plot.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plot.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plot.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
plot.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```

In my df I have every month in this period, so I want to show every month in the x ticks, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can set the xtick labels:

```
plot.set_xticklabels(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']) # etc for all months
```